# Using jquery to change background of an element created with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, jquery-hover

I am trying to display search results on my page for a list of people then allow the user to select one of those search results.

I create a table of people using jquery, which each row having a class of `.searchResult` and I want to highlight (or change background) of that row on hover but it doesn't seem to work the way I'm doing it.

Is there an issue arising because they are rows that I have made after the page was loaded? Or is there an issue with changing the background color of a row?

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('.searchResult').hover(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', '#ff0')
    });
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle for how I'm trying to allow an action on the newly created rpws: http://jsfiddle.net/uxWwZ/

Comment: Could you include HTML and preferably use http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Adding it with CSS worked like a charm. Is there a general rule for when to add effects with CSS and when to use JS?

Comment: Yes; use pure CSS whenever possible, JS only when necessary. :-)

Comment: If possible use css, if not use JS. Css is most likely less coding and less frustration if possible. If you use effects like transitions, timers etc. JS is more likely your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with pure CSS:

```
.searchResult:hover td {
    background-color: #ff0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/6Pme2/

Comment: Just in case there's a table nested inside the `td`, you better limit the selector to direct children, with `.children()` instead of `.find()` in the first example and `.searchResult > td` in the second.

Comment: @Boaz That wouldn't make any difference; all the backgrounds would be changed at the same time.

Comment: .searchResult:hover td doesn't necessarily need "td" unless he has specified a background for td... you can set backgrounds to a tr perfectly fine.

Comment: @Blazemonger It could very well be that the child elements will not have a `:hover` behavior, in which case you will be overriding their background. In general, I find it best to select exactly what's needed.

Comment: @Blazemonger sorry I did not set the background for the tr or anything at the beginning. It did not work when I included tr in the css but it did when I included td. Why is that? Isn't changing the background of the tr and not the td?

Comment: I think it's browser-dependent. The `tr` background should propagate down to its `td`s, but I've noticed it doesn't always do so.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going with the CSS answer, but if you must stay with JQuery, you need to use delegation since they are being added after page load.

```
$(function(){
    $(body).on('hover','.searchResult',function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', '#ff0')
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you've correctly identified the problem; however, your code won't change the bgcolor back when the mouse moves away.

Comment: Good point. Didn't even think of that. Was simply answering his question of why his code above wasn't working.

Comment: This is useful as I'm going to need to add links to each of those created rows and I think this will come in handy.

Comment: @AndrewMcGivery this doesn't seem to be working with my jsfiddle I included just now. Do you know why?

Comment: I got it to work, the version of jquery that my company was using was outdated so I just had to put in the newest version.